# Switch to next Tab on Tab key press when on last control of a TabItem

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, tabs

I'm making a Desktop application using WPF where I have a window with few buttons and a tab control with dynamically created multiple tab items. Each tab item has lot of controls in it.

I want to move to the next tab item after tab press the last control on my current tab item. Right now it just cycles through all controls on the entire window and same tab item. I have set the tab indexes and I tried setting KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once" and Also Local, Cycle, Continue, etc.. but it didn't help.

As shown in the image below, when I press tab on "Date of Arrest", I want to move to the first control on "Texas" Tab but it will just go back to the "Name" control on same tab.

[image: Move to next tab on tab key press]

Answer (score 1):

When pressing `Control+Tab` the next tab is displayed and the first control in that tab will have focus. To navigate backwards use `Control+Shift+Tab`.

Answer (score 1):

Your tabs must have the `Name` property set (`x:Name` in `XAML`). The "last" item on the tab must also have the `Name` property set.

Now set the `TabControl` object's `KeyDown` (or `KeyUp`) event:

```
Debug.WriteLine("key pressed: " + e.Key);
if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
{
    if (btnButton.IsFocused) tab2.Focus();
}
```

The `Debug.WriteLine(...)` is only to make sure the key is being captured, comment or remove that line once everything is working.

Focusing on tabs in sequence requires a few extra lines of code. Here is the complete `KeyDown` event:

```
private void tabControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("key pressed: " + e.Key);
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        var tabs = tabControl.Items.Cast<TabItem>().ToArray();

        var tab=tabs.Select((t, i)=>new {i, t}).SingleOrDefault(t => t.t.IsSelected); // one has to be selected. result is null of no tabs are present (then why have a tab control?)

        if (tab == null) return;
        switch (tab.i)
        {
            case 0:
                if (btnButton.IsFocused)
                    tab2.Focus();
                break;
            case 1:
                tab3.Focus();
                break;
            case 2:
                tab4.Focus();
                break;
            case 3:
                tab1.Focus(); // jump to first?
                // OR do something else
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the `btnButton` with your "last" item on the form.

Comment: I have thought about this approach and this will work but for that I need to manually identify the controls that are last and also find out which tab is next in each tab item which might not be hard in a general scenario but, in my case, all tabs are dynamically generated and differ based on some parameters defined by customer. So, the tab order might not be same for all customers. Also, tabs might not even be added in some scenarios, ex, if customer does not want or have fingerprint system, the "Fingerprint" Tab won't be generated. (Contd..)

Comment: Similarly, controls within each tab might also be present or not present based on various parameters and application modes.  This makes it difficult to find the last control on a tab item. Most of all, if I it will not be a good approach to manually define all this. So, I was wondering Is there something that wpf provides inbuilt for this? Thanks!

Comment: You could do this for a `KeyDown` (or `KeyUp`) event of the specific last control, instead of doing it on the `TabControl` itself. Then it would literally be a one-liner, something like `if (e.Key==Key.Tab) tabX.Focus();` where `tabX` is the tab you want to activate.

Comment: I'm doing it using the concept provided by you for now but leaving the question open in case there is are other ways. Thanks!